# Get Jenkins workspacedirs from master with Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

At first I try to give out my workspacefiles from slave-nodes with this code and it works :

```
 import Jenkins.*

 jenkins = Jenkins.instance

 for (slave in jenkins.nodes) {
     try {

         wsNodes = slave.getWorkspaceRoot()
         println("workspaceRoot: " + wsNodes)

         for (dir in wsNodes.list()) {
             try {
               println("   dirname:  " + dir )
             }catch (Exception e) {
                println("! Error in slave processing: ${e}")
             }
         }
    }catch (Exception e) {
      println("! Error in slave processing: ${e}")
    }
}
```

I only find solutions for this with the slaves. Is there a solution to get the workspacedirs from the master-node ?

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet below should do what you want:

```
import Jenkins.*
jenkins = Jenkins.instance
String jenkinsMasterWorkspace = jenkins.getRawWorkspaceDir()
```